# FCM token doesn't call didReceiveRegistrationToken

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hi using `FCM` into my application.

When I am trying to read `FCM` token even compiler don't call this delegate method also is any way please help.

when I put breaks and check this method is don't call I using ios11 swift4

```
extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate{

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Message data:", remoteMessage.appData)
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
 didReceiveRegistrationToken
```

is a delegate function. it will get called upon receiving token form firebase. if it's not getting called make sure you've following code in AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    return true
}
```

with  `Messaging.messaging().delegate = self` we are registering `AppDelegate` for receiving the method call from Firebase

Comment: my mistake was FirebaseApp.configure() is later than Messaging.messaging().delegate = self . Changing it according to the code above fixed my issue, thanks

Comment: Precisely what happened to my app. Not knowingly, I moved the `configureApp` call after setting the messaging delegate. Using the proper order resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I knew this and still came here for answers as I had forgot. So just a polite reminder. The calls will not be made in the simulator. Ensure to be on real device :-)

Answer (score 0):

I using the following function it is working fine

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        if let refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
           print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
        }
    }
```